# How can I get Current User Email in Redmine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I created plug in for Redmine using Ruby On Rails.
In index.html.erb [View] I want information related logged in person .

```
<h2>ResourcemanagController#index</h2>

<%= User.current.name %>
<%= User.current.id %>
<% if User.current.admin? %>
Admin
<% end %>
```

Using above code I am able to get User name , But I want email address of Current User. What to do ?

Comment: What happens when you try `User.current.email` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= User.current.login %>
```

Using Above Code We can get Email Address of Logged In Person in Redmine.

Answer (score 0):

As of Redmine 5.0.2,
`<%= User.current.mail%>`
should get you the current user's email address: